# PDF doesn't wrap text lines automatically & respect line position

Tags: c#, pdf

I'm trying to generate a PDF via code because not all actual PDF .NET libraries support the new Windows Runtime for Windows/Windows Phone 8.1.
The PDF is saved correctly, with only a bug of stream position count that I can fix easily, but, as you can see, the text doesn't wrap if line is too long.

[image: pdf_printed]

I tried with PDF NewLine char (\n), but C# automatically convert it in the input string
Also, I can't understand the position of lines or objects to put into the document, because I follow this [guide online](http://www.gnupdf.org/Introduction_to_PDF#How_to_read_the_file) that talk about a reversing axis disposition (x for height and y for width), but seems I didn't catch the right methodology (I put in my code a constant left position, at 40, and a variable top descreasing value (from 600, I'm not manage now the multipage if the value is less than 0).

This is the code of PDF generated:

```
http://pastebin.com/ZkZmbJdM
```

(Sorry if I use Pastebin, but using this editor Code function the code seems to be unformatted for special characters used for it)

Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PDF is a graphical format trying to make you think it's a document format. But nope, it's just like drawing with GDI+ for instance. This is the reason why it can achieve the same rendered output across many platforms/programs/etc as opposed to text flow formats like doc/docx. And also, this is why it can really render anything.

So, as opposed to document formats, it is the responsibility of the program that generates the PDF to get the layout right. Think of it just as if you'd draw with GDI+.

In documents like docx or html, it's the rendering program that has to do the layout work. With such document, you just write text and the viewer will take care of laying it out.

Your PDF library certainly has the necessary code to measure the text length. Maybe even it has some code to provide some layout capabilities. You'll have to use these functions to do the layout.

Comment: Infact I don't use any library. I use, for the string width, a fake TextBlock created programmatically by given a specific FontSize and FontFamily, I extract the ActualWidth property after the Arrange and Measure method call of the TextBlock instance and split the string. But my problem is that the document doesn't create any new line...and I can't understand why.

Comment: I think you should use one text block per line, that's the layout part I was talking about.

Comment: So you are saying me to try to use an indent object for each text line?

n 0 obj
**text line n**
endobj

m 0 obj
**text line m**
endobj

And so on?

Comment: Not really. Look at page 311 of the [reference](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/pdf/PDFReference.pdf). You can write `(first line) ' (second line) '`

Comment: It works! Now I must only resolve the auto-wrap that doesn't work, but I think I could elaborate a function that calculate better the string width. Thanks a lot!

Comment: My recommendation is to use a PDF library because it will save you a lot of time. There are libraries for Windows Phone such as ComponentOne PDF, Syncfusion PDF, Xfinium.Pdf just to name a few.